# Dynamic CSS with SQL and PHP

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have hit a wall with this one, here is the scenario:
User 1 clicks not available, div backgrounds gets set to red and updates on everyone elses screen.

CSS:

```
#User1 
{
    background-color: green; <--The one I need to change.
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    margin-left:-8px;
    margin-top:-8px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<head><link href="css/HTML.CSS" rel="stylesheet"><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5"></head>
<body>
<div id="User1"></div>
</body>
</HTML>
```

So the question is how can i go about reading the CSS value from my SQL database? I can write to it fine, thats not a problem, but how do i get it to update that value to be read by everyone.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Yes use jquery http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: you don't do it like this. Prepare CSS classes for such scenarios and append them to the container:like `<div class="click-container"></div>`when clicked: `<div class="click-container error"></div>` or use inline-styling for emergencies `style="background-color: red;"`

Comment: I removed your PHP and SQL Tag because the question you are asking is kind of ambiguous. First you need to have the information from your database and then you have to work with it. With the HTML and CSS given, we may only tell you, how to change your DOM. If you want to know how to retrieve the information from the DB please feel free to open a new question with SQL etc. given. This will be the other half (frontend) of your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic php-css file and use cache to store it temporary (so that request count can be saved)

Create a php file and set header content type as `text/css`

```
header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
//Your sql queries goes here
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [less.css](http://lesscss.org/) to program dynamically css code.
The server will process your styles.less and convert it into .css files.